# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IImageList'

Tags: c#, shell

I'm using [this article code](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/SysImageList/article.asp) to extract the extra large icons. Everything works fine as long as I call its method GetIcon from UI Thread. But if I call from other thread, it throws this error

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IImageList'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
'{46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950}' failed due to the following error: 
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I cant use UI thread for extracting thousands of icons. Any solution ?

Comment: Be sure to make the SHGetImageList call on the worker thread, not the UI thread.  And make sure you use Thread and called SetApartmentState() to make it STA.

Comment: yes problem was fixed when I used the constructor in same thread I need to use IconIndex. But I still don't get why it reacts like that.

Comment: There's no proxy registered for that interface.